# Does Vow of Poverty require you to starve?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats

So, this was clearly not intended, but I'm looking back at the Vow of Poverty with a legalist's eye, and I see the following.

> To fulfill your vow, you must not own or use any material possessions,
> with the following exceptions:
> ...
> You may carry enough food to sustain you for one day in a simple
> (nonmagic) sack or bag.
> ...
> If you break your vow, you immediately and irrevocably lose the
> benefit of this feat.  You may not take another feat to replace it.

It says that you must not own or use, with the following exceptions... and the exception on food is one about carrying (owning) it.  As far as I can tell, no exception is given for actually allowing you to *eat* the food, or even take it out of the bag and hold it in your hand for an extended period of time.

I suppose that you could wait until 5th level, where the Vow itself will provide for your food needs.  If you have a very good friend who is capable of casting 4th-level cleric spells, they could cast sustain on you for however long you might need to *make* it to 5th level.  Otherwise, though, it seems that the "vow of poverty at level 1" builds may be in trouble.

Is this correct?

Comment: So... apparently there are a fair numebr of people who disapprove of this question.  Might i ask why?

Comment: I can't speak for downvoters, but my guess it this falls afoul of (intentionally or accidentally) misreading the rules, thus creating the problem for itself and not being being useful. Comments to this effect have a habit of starting arguments, so users usually don't. Meta reading starting here: [Is it ok to ask for comments on downvotes?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9717) if you wish.

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem well enough for a green check?

Comment: @ThomasMarkov I started out my question with "this was clearly not intended" and asking for a legalist/RAW answer - primarily on the distinction between "carry" and "use".  You responded with a largely RAI answer about the essence of the vow.  No, it does not sufficiently address the question in my opinion

Comment: @BenBarden Then your question needs more details. In what real at-table context is approaching the question this way even beneficial?

Comment: @ThomasMarkov First, I don't see how there are any additional details necessary here.  It's asking a question about the rules as written, and the both the rules in question and the question about them are clearly indicated.  That should be all the details that are necessary.  As for use at the table - primarily as a particularly egregious example to demonstrate to your DM that the rules surrounding the Vow are broken and need houserules, or to demonstrate to your players that the rules surrounding the Vow are broken and that they should pick something else.

Comment: @BenBarden My answer has clearly demomstrated that the rules are not broken, house rules are not needed, and the class is fine to play.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov you are entitled to believe that.  I do not concur, for reasons I have already explained, and therefore am not providing a checkmark.  If you wish to try to convince me that I am incorrect, we can take it to chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120345/discussion-between-thomas-markov-and-ben-barden).

Answer (score 14):

#### Give us this day our daily bread.

The feat states:

> To fulfill your vow, you must not own or use any material possessions.

It goes on to explain how we are to relate to food under the vow:

> You may carry enough food to sustain you for one day in a simple (nonmagic) sack or bag.

*Enough food for one day is not "material possessions"*. It will be gone tomorrow. We aren't keeping any more than we need right now. It is our daily bread. This is the essence of our vow. To never have excess. It's a vow of poverty, not a vow of death.

Comment: definition of "material possessions" seems to be "property or belongings that are tangible".  Applicale definition of "property" seems to be "a thing or things belonging to someone; possessions collectively."  I'm not clear on how this disallows food.  Beyond that... I'm not trying to suggest that this was the *intended* effect of the Vow.  It's just that the feat itself is poorly written in a number of ways when taken as written, and this seems to be merely the most egregious.

Comment: @BenBarden If you read it in the context of "this class feature is obviously not supposed to make you die", it's abundantly clear what it means and charges of being poorly written don't hold water.